# android: How to make a tab flip like android market?

Tags: android, tabs, widget, fragment

i wanna rewrite my app to fragment api, TabHost is deprecated so i've found ViewPager, but how can i make a tabbar like android market? (android market use viewpager and a bar). Superuser 3 use this bar too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this guide:
http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

Answer (score 4):

The technique is called "Swipey Tabs" and is described by Kirill Grouchnikov, a google user interface engineer, in [this blog post](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/08/11/android-tips-and-tricks-swipey-tabs.html).

Andreas Stütz has done a project to replicate the functionality called [android-viewpagertabs](https://github.com/astuetz/android-viewpagertabs). Other people have [had a go too](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/).

Answer (score 1):

i think you looking for the viewflipper class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about Honeycomb, but in Ice Cream Sandwhich it happens automaticly when adding enough tabs to the actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

The guy who created ActionBarSherlock as a project for this type of functionality, called ViewPageIndicator.  Here's the URL: http://viewpagerindicator.com/