# Android Fragment Pager - how to create fragment tile like i have given below?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

[image]

In my application i am using Sherlock Fragment Pager and i want to create this type of title for each of my fragment.
Middle header is for current fragment which is currently showing and head title of previous and next screen at corner.

Comment: I think this is tab and you can add them easily ... Is there any issue them adding as tab?

Comment: I am using actionbar sherlock library. Can i create this by using actionbar sherlock library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android: How to make a tab flip like android market?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971758/android-how-to-make-a-tab-flip-like-android-market)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [this](https://github.com/ChainsDD/Superuser/blob/master/src/com/noshufou/android/su/widget/PagerHeader.java) in all of my applications for that effect.

Comment: Is it a library project ? I am using action bar sherlock library and i am not interested in using any other library.

Comment: It isn't, just use it individually.

Comment: How to use this PagerHeader.java widget class ? I searched in layout and in src to find where this widget is placed ? I also import this project in eclipse but it has so many errors. So please tell me how is it works ?

Answer (score 2):

The guy who created ActionBarSherlock as a project for this type of functionality, called ViewPageIndicator. Here's the URL: http://viewpagerindicator.com/.

I think this will give you the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971758/android-how-to-make-a-tab-flip-like-android-market).

To summarise it :

- There is an article by Kirill Grouchnikov about this design interface [here](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/08/11/android-tips-and-tricks-swipey-tabs.html).
- You can also check [this](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) project and [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/) project. Both of them seem to try to replicate this kind of interface.