# I don't know what this kind of Android navigation is called

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationbar

In the screenshot below the title bar, I need to create this type of navigation.  I'm not looking for a 'teach-me', but just a finger pointing me somewhere.  Is this a native droid element?  If so, what is it called so I can RTFM!  I've seen it before but I can't remember where.  -- Or do I need to build a custom frag.

[Example of what it looks like](http://dev.marketingclique.com/nav-example.png)

Comment: Your link is broken. Update your question

Comment: Umm no, the link seems fine (at least now it does, about 4 minutes after you posted).

Comment: @Andrew - care to describe what below the title bar you are trying to find the name of.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about the ViewPager...see here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

and here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

> *JosephL*
>
> The technique is called "Swipey Tabs" and is described by Kirill
>   Grouchnikov, a google user interface engineer, in this blog post.
>
> Andreas Stütz has done a project to replicate the functionality called
>   android-viewpagertabs. Other people have had a go too.

[Link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971758/android-how-to-make-a-tab-flip-like-android-market)